# SSRS 2008 - Reporting Services Webpage is Blank except for headers

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm getting blank page when I open the Report Manager: I've got a header - "...Reporting... HOME", and then just empty space.

I'm on SQL 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Any ideas how to fix?  I've confirmed that I am logged in as a local administrator.  I tried adding the URL to trusted sites but that didn't seem to help either.

**Update**

When I go to the ReportServer URL I get this error message:

```
Reporting Services Error
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The permissions granted to user 'DTNT\greg' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied) Get Online Help 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL Server Reporting Services
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it, sort of! I tried right clicking IE and selecting run as administrator, and then going to the report manager URL and everything worked properly.

I clicked on site settings on the top right of the page and added the greg user as a system administrator and system user.

I also added the greg user as a content manager on the root directory.

IT still says I was already a local administrator on that machine, but this seemed to be required to make it work.

Any thoughts why that was necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540800/sql-2008-reporting-services-i-have-no-rights.

Basically you will run into this problem with UAC, if your only rights are via the builtin\adimistrators group, in order to make windows "see" this you need to run elevated, if you added your windows account explicitly as a content manger all would be good as you discovered.

This behavior would be the same for a sql server accessing via SSMS where the only access was granted to builtin\Admiistrators and not your user account explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds suspiciously like the account you are using to access the Report Manager does not have permissions to view content. Depending on how you have things setup it may not be enough to be a local admin to see content.

On the home page of the Report Manager try clicking on the Properties tab and click New Role Assignment and manually adding your username and assigning it to all of the available roles.

If that does not work then you may need to login to the Report Server via the SQL Server Management Studio and double check how the security is setup. Make sure you connect to a report server and not a database engine.

Comment: Report Manager is just a blank page that says "Reporting Services" at the top.  There are no tabs or anything else to click on.

How do I set up the security via SQL Server Management studio?

Comment: Try going to the ReportServer folder in the SSRS site (http://ServerName/ReportServer) instead and see if you get an error message.

Comment: @Greg: Sorry I was so vague. I don't have SSRS installed on this laptop so its hard to give specifics. Hopefully someone else can chime in.

Comment: @mrdenny, I updated the question with the error message I got from the ReportServer site.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Greg, yep that's what I expected to see. What rights does the "DTNT\greg" account have in the SSRS databases?

Answer (score 0):

You will also see this issue if you're running the SSRS service under a domain account.  In that case you will see a completely blank page regardless if you are running as adminstrator or not, but it will work in other browsers like Firefox.  This is an issue with Kerberos authentication, there are a couple of options to fix it detailed in [this article](http://www.localwisdom.com/blog/2009/10/ssrs-2008-not-authenticating-in-ie-but-works-in-firefox/).